# How would I install a window AC on an awning window?

Tags: air-conditioning

My house I'm renting was unfortunately made with awning windows. The window I want to place a window AC is a single pane large awning window that winds out. I certainly do not want to go with a portable AC as they're useless, and I have tried those already. What would be the best way to alter the frame to support a window AC?

Comment: Altering the frame of a rental unit is a no-no unless you have the owner's permission.

Comment: I have permission.

Comment: They're not useless at all.  You do, however, have to know how to install them.  A botch job there will defeat the purpose.

Comment: Are the portable units really that bad?  I thought they worked the same as a window uint as long as they were properly vented outside.  That would have been my suggestion, so sorry they didn't work for you.

Comment: I would recommend giving the portable units another chance.  Read and clearly follow all installation instructions regarding venting.  
Changing out a window like your situation is a very big and complicated project.